# What is the difference between a Control template and a Display template?

Tags: display-template, template

I have tried to read up on it but I am still confused regarding them.

If I want to change the look and feel of page when I click on an item in a list/library ( the dispform.aspx) page, what file(s) do I need to change ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The control templates and display templates are terminologies used for Search in SP 2013.

> Display Templates
>
> Display Templates are used with CSWP to format/style search result
>   generated by CSWP search query. Display Templates control which
>   managed property is shown in the search results and how they appear in
>   the Web Part. Each Display Template has two files: an HTML version of
>   the Display Template that you can edit in your HTML editor, and a .js
>   file that is for SharePoint use and should never be modified. CSWP
>   uses combination of two Display Templates, Control Templates and Item
>   Templates to render results.
>
> Control Template provides HTML to structure the overall layout for how
>   you want to present the search results. For example, the Control
>   Template might provide the HTML for a heading, beginning and end of a
>   list. The Control Template is rendered only once in the Web Part.
>   See this for more information:
>   http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_quick_reads/archive/2013/09/03/3588171.aspx

However, this is not relevant to customizing the dispform.aspx. The display form can be customized in several ways like in SharePoint Designer, Info Path or using Client Side Rendering technique which is new in SP 2013. You can read more about it here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views

Comment: Thanks. Much clearer picture now. I will read up on Client Side rendering, looks like that is the newest(best?) way to customize DispForm.aspx.